# error in file get contents and var_dump

Tags: php, bots, telegram

i use this code:

```
<?php
$token="683911895:AAGGVHW_RdP9h4dfvXYPABJe-RGdfyj125g";
$url="https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/getupdates";

$content=file_get_contents($url);

var_dump ($content);
?>
```

but it have 2 errors:

1:
 Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. in C:\wamp\www\tbot.php on line 5

2:
 Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.telegram.org/bot683911895:AAGGVHW_RdP9h4dfvXYPABJe-RGdfyj125g/getupdates): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. in C:\wamp\www\tbot.php on line 5

and telegram is ban in my country

Answer (score 0):

check php settings "allow_url_fopen = On"

check the usage here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

if it still will not connect then you have an issue with the URL or DNS on your server.